# Hibernate createSQLQuery give me I/O Error: Sofware caused connection abort on SqlServer 2008 RS1

Tags: sql-server, spring, hibernate

Im using SqlServer FREETEXTTABLE to search some products on a view, passing 3 parameters, the Strings to search, the first row to return and the last row to return (the usual pagination).

The code goes like this:

```
public List searchProducto(final String claves,final  Integer pagina, final Integer nroFilas) {

    return getHibernateTemplate().executeFind(new HibernateCallback() {
        public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
           String sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RANK DESC) AS RowNr, * FROM vista_web_productos AS vwp INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE( producto,clave,:name) as ftt ON ftt.[KEY]=vwp.id_web) t WHERE RowNr BETWEEN :inicio AND :fin";                
            SQLQuery query = (SQLQuery) session.createSQLQuery(sql);
            query.addEntity(VistaWebProductoVO.class).setString("name",claves).setInteger("inicio", ((pagina - 1) * nroFilas)+1 ).setInteger("fin", ((pagina) * nroFilas)  );

            List list = query.list();
            return list;
        }
    });
}
```

When I test the code , sometimes it works (usually the first time works ok and them) and sometimes it doesnt. Specialy if I debug my test and i dont press the continue button (f5) immediatly it just doesnt work. Any ideas with the cause of the problem? Im using also Spring 3.